# Find the form of $f(x,y)$  knowing the form of contour lines in the $XZ$  and  $YZ$  planes

Tags: 3d, tomography

I am trying to find the form of $z=f(x,y)$. I know that:

Contour lines in the $XZ$ plane are of the form: $$z=A*ln(x)+B$$ 
(the $A$ and $B$ parameters vary with $y$)

Contour lines in the $YZ$ plane are of the form: $$z=Cy^2+Dy+E$$ 
(the $C$, $D$ and $E$ parameters vary with $x$)

What is then the form of $z=f(x,y)$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by $A$ and $B$ varying with $y$ in the context of contour lines in the $XZ$ plane (and likewise for $x$ and $YZ$). I'll assume what you mean is that there is a function $z=f(x,y)$ and the first equation describes the relationship between $x$ and $z$ if you hold $y$ fixed and the second equation describes the relationship between $y$ and $z$ if you hold $x$ fixed.

Since the two expressions for $z$ have to be equal, the dependency of the parameters on $y$ in the first equation must be such that a quadratic function of $y$ results for all $x$. Since $\ln x$ takes different values for different $x$, this can only happen if $A$ and $B$ are both quadratic functions of $y$. Thus, the most general form for $z$ compatible with the given conditions is

$$z=(a_2y^2+a_1y+a_0)\ln x+b_2y^2+b_1y+b_0$$

with

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
A&=&a_2y^2+a_1y+a_0\;,\\
B&=&b_2y^2+b_1y+b_0\;,\\
C&=&a_2\ln x+b_2\;,\\
D&=&a_1\ln x+b_1\;,\\
E&=&a_0\ln x+b_0\;.\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$